# couldn't write /root/.xscreensaver

Tags: windows, screensaver, xscreensaver

I know it's still quite experimental stuff and maybe not suited for this forum but nevertheless:

I'm using ubuntu on windows 10 and would like to run xscreensaver (because I love that program :-D).

I used [this guide](http://www.howtogeek.com/261575/how-to-run-graphical-linux-desktop-applications-from-windows-10s-bash-shell/) and can run gvim (but I don't love that program ;)

I installed xscreensaver (with apt-get) and it runs but doesn't want to show screensavers... (with error in title).

Which is quite a pitty because that's exactly what I want it to do ;)

I'm not intending to use xscreensaver as a 'real' screensaver in windows 10 because I guess that won't be possible/very hard but if you could get me closer to just get a fullscreen/partial screen of some of that nice open source eye candy you would really make my day!!!

I googled around (a bit) and other people in other situations have similar errors but no one seems to have a real solution.

You would really make my day, my week and even my month (and the month after that) but if it is not possible for some reason it would be a pitty but not a big one,

thanks for reading and I really hope you have a solution ;)

S.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

never mind,

xscreensaver didn't had write rights on my home dir,

I created a user and set permissions for it.

Comment: I can't do that yet (not enough reputation, only in 2 days...)